# PyQt5 - Herdar informações de uma classe para outra. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt-5

Criei duas janelas no PyQt5, onde a primeira janela precisa herdar informações da segunda, nesse exemplo eu criei:

- **Tela_1**: que contém um *"QLineEdit"* para digitação e um *"QPushButton"* para abrir a outra janela.
- **Tela_2**: também contém um *"QLineEdit"* para digitação e um *"QPushButton"* para levar as informações do texto digitado para a janela 1

No exemplo abaixo a classe **Tela_1** tem uma função com o nome *"completa_campos"* que irá receber informações do que foi digitado no *"QLineEdit"* da **Tela_2** e completar essa informação no *"QLineEdit"* da **Tela_1**

```
from sys import argv, exit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton

class Tela_1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tela_1, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Tela 1 - TESTE")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 400) 
        
        self.janela2 = Tela_2() 

        # ADD WIDGETS        
        self.texto_final = QLineEdit()
        self.botao_add = QPushButton()
        self.botao_add.setText("Add")
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.texto_final)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.botao_add)      
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.botao_add.clicked.connect(self.abrir_janela2)
    
    def abrir_janela2(self):
        self.janela2.show()
    
    def completa_campo(self, texto):
        print("O valor digitado foi: ", texto)
        self.texto_final.setText(texto)

class Tela_2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tela_2, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Tela 2 - TESTE")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 200)         

        # ADD WIDGETS      
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setText("Digite algo e clique no botão")
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.pushButton = QPushButton()
        self.pushButton.setText("Adicionar dados")        
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)        
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.envia_dados)
    
    def envia_dados(self):
        self.janela_1 = Tela_1()

        dados = self.lineEdit.text()        
        if dados != "":
            self.janela_1.completa_campo(texto=dados)
            self.hide()

app = QApplication(argv)
w = Tela_1()
w.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

No código acima não está trazendo essas informações, ele até consegue imprimir na tela o que foi digitado, mas não completa o "QLineEdit" quando uso .setText().

Como faço para herdar as informações de um "QLineEdit" de outra janela sem precisar iniciar janela atual novamente?

Comment: Oi Rafael, apenas um adendo: o termo mais preciso seria "transportar informações entre Widgets". Quando falamos em "herdar" dentro de programação, logo se pensa em classes derivadas herdando seus métodos e atributos de suas respectivas classes básicas, que não é o que você quer aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o que você quer é uma janela secundária que abre, pega um valor e o retorna para a janela principal, você pode fazer com que sua janela secundária herde de um `QDialog`. Essa classe possui um método chamado `exec_` que facilita muito isso - precisamos apenas explicar para a janela secundária em que momento o diálogo é "aceito", ligando por exemplo o sinal `self.pushButton.clicked` com o método `self.accept`, que herdamos do `QDialog`.

Aqui um exemplo que faz o que você deseja (tomei a liberdade de simplificar um pouco o código). Agora toda vez em que o botão da `Tela1` é clicado, ele cria o diálogo (`Tela2`) e espera que ele seja aceito (neste caso, que o botão seja clicado), e aí lida com o valor retornado. Espero que esteja claro o suficiente:

```
from sys import argv, exit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QDialog


class Tela_1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Tela 1 - TESTE")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 400) 
        
        # CREATE LAYOUT
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        
        # CREATE WIDGETS      
        self.texto_final = QLineEdit()
        self.botao_add = QPushButton("Add")

        # ADD WIDGETS TO LAYOUT
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.texto_final)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.botao_add)      

        # ADD CONNECT WIDGETS
        self.botao_add.clicked.connect(self.abrir_janela2)
    
    def abrir_janela2(self):
        texto_retornado = Tela_2().exec_()
        if texto_retornado:
            self.texto_final.setText(texto_retornado)


class Tela_2(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Tela 2 - TESTE")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 200)
        
        # CREATE LAYOUT
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        # CREATE WIDGETS      
        self.label = QLabel("Digite algo e clique no botão")
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Adicionar dados")
        
        # ADD WIDGETS TO LAYOUT
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
        # CONNECT WIDGETS
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)
    
    def exec_(self):
        if super().exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            return self.lineEdit.text()
        

app = QApplication(argv)
w = Tela_1()
w.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```